# SQLAlchemy placeholder do not work well

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I construct SQL statement as a string literal, and pass it to SQLAlchemy execute method.
To avoid the SQL injection, I used the place holder, but it's not work well.
When I used special words like, "!, &", it become error.
p.s I use flask-sqlalchemy

This is the code.

```
sql = ""
sql += "SELECT count(*) "
sql += "FROM mytable, to_tsquery('english',%(kstr)s) query "
sql += "WHERE query @@ tsv "
res = db.engine.execute(sql, kstr = keyquery)
```

keyquery is search words, and if keyquery include special words like as '!, &'
it become error....

This is error message, it contains Japanese because of my machine environment.

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) tsquery内の構文エラー: "USA!"
"SELECT count(*) FROM mytable, to_tsquery('english',%(kstr)s) query WHERE query @@ tsv " {'kstr': u'USA!'}
```

Now, I'm skkiping NG words as this.

```
keyquery = .replace("!'","").replace('$','')......
```

But, this way, I cannot search words that includes special words, like as 'USA!'
How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: If you're just going to use plain SQL why not just use the DB api directly? Just skip sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Try `plainto_tsquery()` instead of `to_tsquery()`. Relevant [PostgreSQL full text search documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES).